# Frontend form to change Craft Commerce user's password?

Tags: password, frontend-form, plugin-craftcommerce2

I'm trying to modify Craft 3's example '[Change password](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/set-password-form.html#app)' form to work with a logged in Commerce 2 user, and have copied that code to `templates/setpassword.twig`.

Two problems...

(1) The {{ code }} and {{ id }} variables throw *Don't exist* errors.

(2) If I comment those variables out, I get a *Page not found/"Unable to resolve the request: users/setPassword"* error when submitting the form.

Clearly I'm doing this totally wrong ... can anyone set me straight?

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
{{ csrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/set-password">
<input type="hidden" name="code" value="{{ code }}">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ id }}">

<h3><label for="newPassword">New Password</label></h3>
<input id="newPassword" type="password" name="newPassword">
{% if errors is defined %}
    <ul class="errors">
        {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Is this for when a user forgets their password, or do you want a form that allows them to change their password at their leisure?

Comment: One that lets them change it at leisure : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you are currently using is for the `Set Password` form that is used when a user forgets their password and you send them a `Password reset email` as documented at https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/set-password-form.html.

Here is what I'm using to allow users to **change** their passwords on demand. It is based on the `User Profile Form` documented at https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/user-profile-form.html

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/save-user">
    {# Change to suit your needs #}
    {{ redirectInput('users/'~currentUser.username) }}
    {# Get logged-in user's ID #}
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

    {% macro errorList(errors) %}
        {% if errors %}
            <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}

    {% from _self import errorList %}

    {# Enter current password #}
    <h3><label for="password">Current Password</label></h3>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password">

    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(user.getErrors('password')) }}
    {% endif %}

    {# Enter new password #}
    <h3><label for="newPassword">New Password</label></h3>
    <input id="newPassword" type="password" name="newPassword">

    {% if account is defined %}
        {{ errorList(user.getErrors('newPassword')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

UPDATE: updated form to include error handling.

Answer (score -1):

I [raised a PR](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/pull/206) for this last week but it was closed. Apparently you're not supposed to load those templates from the front end as those variables are not auto-populated by craft. ([This code](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/pull/206/commits/8ad7fd8ea1a7b3915d77d1b2a9fe3bebadafa46c) fixes the problem)

Comment: Note: use that on your own risk. I wouldn't recommend doing so